# Axios in Quasar Cordova Build Not Working

Tags: laravel, cordova, axios, vuejs3, quasar-framework

When building for Cordova my Axios request fails with status 404.

While when I do quasar dev locally works perfectly to the same endpoint,

I tried to look for differences in the trace and the only difference is that from Android the request comes

> from the build:

```
{
   "message":"Request failed with status code 404",
   "name":"Error",
   "stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 404\n    at createError (file:///android_asset/www/assets/axios.f16702dc.js:263:15)\n    at settle (file:///android_asset/www/assets/axios.f16702dc.js:272:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (file:///android_asset/www/assets/axios.f16702dc.js:451:7)",
   "config":{
      "url":"api/registration-stages",
      "method":"post",
      "data":"{\"stage\":1,\"first_name\":\"\",\"middle_name\":\"\",\"last_name\":\"\",\"email_address\":\"\",\"date_of_birth\":\"\"}",
      "headers":{
         "Accept":"application/json",
         "Content-Type":"application/json",
         "api-key":"AAA"
      },
      "baseURL":"https://velvet.globexfrance.com/",
      "transformRequest":[
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[
         null
      ],
      "timeout":0,
      "xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN",
      "xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN",
      "maxContentLength":-1,
      "maxBodyLength":-1,
      "transitional":{
         "silentJSONParsing":true,
         "forcedJSONParsing":true,
         "clarifyTimeoutError":false
      }
   }
}
```

> Trace locally forcing a 404 with wrong url ("api/registration-stageas"):

```
{
   "message":"Request failed with status code 404",
   "name":"Error",
   "stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 404\n    at createError (http://localhost:9000/node_modules/.q-cache/vite/spa/deps/axios.js?v=cc902d62:311:19)\n    at settle (http://localhost:9000/node_modules/.q-cache/vite/spa/deps/axios.js?v=cc902d62:327:16)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:9000/node_modules/.q-cache/vite/spa/deps/axios.js?v=cc902d62:555:11)",
   "config":{
      "url":"api/registration-stageas",
      "method":"post",
      "data":"{\"stage\":1,\"first_name\":\"\",\"middle_name\":\"\",\"last_name\":\"\",\"email_address\":\"\",\"date_of_birth\":\"\"}",
      "headers":{
         "Accept":"application/json",
         "Content-Type":"application/json",
         "api-key":"AAA"
      },
      "baseURL":"https://velvet.globexfrance.com/",
      "transformRequest":[
         null
      ],
      "transformResponse":[
         null
      ],
      "timeout":0,
      "xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN",
      "xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN",
      "maxContentLength":-1,
      "maxBodyLength":-1,
      "transitional":{
         "silentJSONParsing":true,
         "forcedJSONParsing":true,
         "clarifyTimeoutError":false
      }
   }
}
```

If someone can understand why this is happening
Quasar v1.1.2
Vue v3
Cordova 11.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I needed the cordova plugin

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.5 "Whitelist"